# MySQL Workbench (where clause is ambiguous")

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT A.first_name, A.last_name, B.title

FROM author A, book B

WHERE A.author_id = B.author_id;
```

I understand that A and B is refer to the table name.

When I run the program with A and B, there is not error. 
but when I run the program without A and B

```
SELECT first_name, last_name,title

FROM author , book 

WHERE author_id = author_id;
```

There is error shown " Error Code: 1052. Column 'author_id' in where clause is ambiguous".

Comment: the database(including derived tables) has more than one  column with `author_id` name, you have to define which one of them do you mean

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Comment: `WHERE author_id = author_id;` ...  I'm confused too.  Do you know which `author_id` belong to which table????  I don't.  Obviously, your dbms doesn't either.

Comment: I know author_id belong to which table already. i understand that there is more than one column with author_id. can i know when to use WHERE?? like WHERE example like WHERE  A.author_id = B.author_id (take from 2 column)and WHERE publisher_name LIKE '%publish%' )(take from 1 column) very confuse.

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE author.author_id= book.author_id;
```